# Edit and Contiue VS2005

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide, editor

I know this has been asked all over the web in various different scenarios, but I can't get a definitive answer, so I though I'd try here.

I'm using VS 2005, with WinForms code. I used to be able to Edit and Continue all over the place, and now, in *some* projects, I can't *type* in the code window. I can techincally Edit and Continue, because I can select and drag code around, but I can't enter any keystrokes into the text editor.

I've tried all the suggestions about makng sure the Edit and Continue is on, Break all Processes, Optimize code is off, Debug symbol generation is set to full.

Is there any chance this is related to source control? The project that is not allowing me to type while it's executing is under source control(Surround SCM w/VS plugin), but the file in question is checked out and not read-only. The only reason I bring that up, is that have no problem with edit and continue in another solution which is not under source control.

Anyone have any ideas?

UPDATE: I can also Undo/Redo while the code is executing, and these changes are executed live, like E&C changes are supposed to be. But still no new keystrokes allowed. The fact that I can make live edits leads me to think this isn't a debugger issue, but a bug in the IDE.

Comment: What happens if, in your project under source control, you make a copy of the file you can't E&C, name it something different, make sure it's not read-only, and replace the troublesome file with the new file in the project. Can you type your edits then?

Comment: You must've restarted VS already.. Well close it. Remove all *.pdb files and any VS specific files (at least *.suo). If you have source control and no significant changes, just remove it all and get it anew. That's pretty much what I did when E&C started to b*tch and moan and it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I don't like this, but it looks like it has something to do with Resharper, or Addins in general. I'm running Resharper 2.5, and when I disable it, the problem goes away and I can E&C just fine. The weird thing is, I was using Resharper on those other projects I mentioned, that weren't in source control, and E&C worked there. So maybe its a 3 way collision of E&C, Resharper and Surround SCM.

I had really gotten used to all these awesome tools, dammit.